# tc shell script: undefined variable

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with set flag1.. i am getting an error of flag1: Undefined variable.

```
if($notLoaded1 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in first load: $notLoaded1"
  set flag1=1
endif

if($notLoaded2 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in second load: $notLoaded2"
  set flag2=1
endif

if($notLoaded3 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in third load: $notLoaded3"
  set flag3=1
endif

echo $flag1
echo $flag2
echo $flag3
```

is there a way to check all three of them in one if statement or rather than using 3 if statements

```
if ($flag1 > 0) then
  exit 1
endif

if ($flag2 > 0) then
  exit 1
endif

if ($flag3 > 0) then
  exit 1
endif
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need 3 flag variables for?

```
set error=0

if ($notLoaded1 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in first load: $notLoaded1"
  set error=1
endif

if ($notLoaded2 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in second load: $notLoaded2"
  set error=1
endif

if ($notLoaded3 > 0) then
  echo "Rows not loaded due to data errors in third load: $notLoaded3"
  set error=1
endif

if ($error) then
  exit 1
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`flag1` only gets set if `$notLoaded1` is greater than 0. So if it's zero, you don't get a $flag1.

I'd suggest initializing those three variables with defaults beforehand:

```
set flag1=0
if (...) the
    set flag1=1
    echo 'Rows not loaded...'
endif
```

That'll guarantee that flag1 always exists.